# How to pass parameters in Powershell Invoke-RestMethod POST

Tags: rest, powershell, post

For the life of me, I'm not sure why I can't get this working - I just want to test my POST method in an ASP.net controller which is specified such:

```
public void Post([FromBody] param1, [FromBody] param2) { 
     Debug.Writeline(param1+":"param2);
}
```

This is the Powershell command I am using to test this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:49879/api/values -Method Post -Body @{param1=test;param2=test2}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What's the error message you are seeing?